# how to stop downloading in android

Tags: android, download

my downloadproccers is :

```
    public class DownloadProcessor extends Thread 
    {
    public static final String TAG = "DownloadProcessor";

    private Download mDownload;

    private HttpGet mMethod = null;
    private DownloadHandler mHandler;

    public boolean mStopped = false;

    private Object lock = new Object();

    public DownloadProcessor(Download dl, DownloadHandler handler)
    {
            mDownload = dl;
            mHandler = handler;
    }

    public Download getDownload()
    {
            return mDownload;
    }

    private HttpClient getClient()
    {
            /* Set the connection timeout to 10s for our test. */
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

            /* Avoid registering the https scheme, and thus initializing
             * SSLSocketFactory on Android.  Seems to be very heavy for some
             * reason. */
            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http",
              PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

            SingleClientConnManager cm =
              new SingleClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
    }

    public void run()
    {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting...");

            HttpClient cli = getClient();
            HttpGet method;

            method = new HttpGet(mDownload.url.toString());

            /* It's important that we pause here to check if we've been stopped
             * already.  Otherwise, we would happily progress, seemingly ignoring
             * the stop request. */
            if (mStopped == true)
                    return;

            synchronized(lock) {
                    mMethod = method;
            }

            HttpEntity ent = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try {
                    HttpResponse resp = cli.execute(mMethod);

                    if (mStopped == true)
                            return;

                    StatusLine status = resp.getStatusLine();

                    if (status.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                            throw new Exception("HTTP GET failed: " + status);

                    if ((ent = resp.getEntity()) != null)
                    {
                            long len;
                            if ((len = ent.getContentLength()) >= 0)
                                    mHandler.sendSetLength(len);

                            in = ent.getContent();
                            out = new FileOutputStream(mDownload.getDestination());

                            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
                            int n;
                            long bytes = 0;

                            /* Note that for most applications, sending a handler message
                             * after each read() would be unnecessary.  Instead, a timed
                             * approach should be utilized to send a message at most every
                             * x seconds. */
                            while ((n = in.read(b)) >= 0)
                            {
                                    bytes += n;
                                    mHandler.sendOnRecv(bytes);     
                                    out.write(b, 0, n);
                            }
                    }

                    if (mStopped == false)
                            mHandler.sendFinished();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    /* We expect a SocketException on cancellation.  Any other type of
                     * exception that occurs during cancellation is ignored regardless
                     * as there would be no need to handle it. */
                    if (mStopped == false)
                    {
                            mHandler.sendError(e.toString());
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected error", e);
                    }
            } finally {
                    if (in != null)
                            try { in.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}

                    synchronized(lock) {
                            mMethod = null;
                    }

                    /* Close the socket (if it's still open) and cleanup. */
                    cli.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

                    if (out != null)
                    {
                            try { 
                                    out.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    mHandler.sendError("Error writing output: " + e.toString());
                                    return;
                            } finally {
                                    if (mStopped == true)
                                            mDownload.abortCleanup();
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    /**
     * This method is to be called from a separate thread.  That is, not the
     * one executing run().  When it exits, the download thread should be on
     * its way out (failing a connect or read call and cleaning up).
     */
    public void stopDownload(boolean _mStopped)
    {
        mStopped=_mStopped;
            /* As we've written this method, calling it from multiple threads would
             * be problematic. */
            if (mStopped == true)
                    return;

            /* Too late! */
            if (isAlive() == false)
                    return;

            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping download...");

            /* Flag to instruct the downloading thread to halt at the next
             * opportunity. */
            mStopped = true;

            /* Interrupt the blocking thread.  This won't break out of a blocking
             * I/O request, but will break out of a wait or sleep call.  While in
             * this case we know that no such condition is possible, it is always a
             * good idea to include an interrupt to avoid assumptions about the
             * thread in question. */
            interrupt();

            /* A synchronized lock is necessary to avoid catching mMethod in
             * an uncommitted state from the download thread. */
            synchronized(lock)
            {
                    /* This closes the socket handling our blocking I/O, which will
                     * interrupt the request immediately.  This is not the same as
                     * closing the InputStream yieled by HttpEntity#getContent, as the
                     * stream is synchronized in such a way that would starve our main
                     * thread. */
                    if (mMethod != null)
                            mMethod.abort();
            }

            mHandler.sendAborted();

            Log.d(TAG, "Download stopped.");
    }

    public void stopDownloadThenJoin()
    {
            stopDownload(true);

            while (true)
            {
                    try {
                            join();
                            break;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
    }

public static class Download
{
    public URL url;
    public boolean directory;
    public File dst;
    public String name;
    public long length;

    public Download(URL url, File dst)
    {
            this.url = url;
            this.dst = dst;

            /* Figure out the filename to save to from the URL.  Note that
             * it would be better to override once the HTTP server responds,
             * since a better name will have been provided, possibly after
             * redirect.  But I don't care right now. */
            if ((directory = dst.isDirectory()) == true)
            {
                    String[] paths = url.getPath().split("/");

                    int n = paths.length;

                    if (n > 0)
                            n--;

                    if (paths[n].length() > 0)
                            name = paths[n];
                    else
                            name = "index.html";
            }
    }

    public File getDestination()
    {
            File f;

            if (directory == true)
                    f = new File(dst.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name);
            else
                    f = dst;

            return f;
    }

    /**
     * Delete the destination file, if it exists.
     */
    public void abortCleanup()
    {
            getDestination().delete();
    }
}
```

}

and my thread is :

```
   public final DownloadHandler mHandler = new DownloadHandler()
{
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
                DownloadProcessor.Download dl = mThread.getDownload();
                notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Downloading", System.currentTimeMillis());
                notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.download);
                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 10, false);
                notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.appName, name);
                ProgressBar status_progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.status_progress);
                Button Cancelbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Cancelbutton);
                status_progress.setMax(100); 

                final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
                switch (msg.what)
                {
                case MSG_FINISHED:
                    notificationManager.cancel(42);
                    Cancelbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    status_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mThread = null;

                        Thread addAppDl=new Thread();
                        addAppDl.start();

                        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/.sabad/"+idApp+".apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive"); 
                        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                        break;
                case MSG_SET_LENGTH:
                        dl.length = (Long)msg.obj;
                        break;
                case MSG_ON_RECV:
                        if (dl.length >= 0)
                        {
                                float prog =
                                  ((float)((Long)msg.obj) / (float)dl.length) * 100f;

                                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, (int)prog, false);
                                notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, (int)prog+"%");
                                status_progress.setProgress((int)prog); 


                                // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
                                notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            float prog =
                                    ((float)((Long)msg.obj) / (float)dl.length) * 100f;
                                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, (int)prog, false);
                                notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, (int)prog+"%");
                                status_progress.setProgress((int)prog); 


                                  // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
                                  notificationManager.notify(42, notification);                            }
                        break;
                case MSG_ERROR:
                    notificationManager.cancel(42);
                    Cancelbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    status_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mThread = null;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + msg.obj,
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                default:
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
        }
};
```

and i start download with this codes:

```
                DownloadProcessor.Download dl = 
              new DownloadProcessor.Download(srcUrl, new File(dst));

            mThread = new DownloadProcessor(dl, mHandler);
            Cancelbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            status_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mThread.start();
```

But I want to stop download,
I use this

```
mThread.mStopped=true;
mThread.stopDownload(true);
```

but it doesn't !

Comment: You have used the AsyncTask!

Comment: plz samples code show thank very very much

Comment: This is an example of using AsyncTask for downloading files : http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. In your while you can do:

```
while ((n = in.read(b)) >= 0) {
    if (mStopped) {
       throw new CanceledException();
    } else {
        bytes += n;
        mHandler.sendOnRecv(bytes);     
        out.write(b, 0, n);
    }
}
```

So, this way you can set mStopped true when your button clicked and your Excepetion will be thrown and your thread will be killed

Comment: i add your codes but eclips error "CanceledException cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: You need to create this exception, but if you don't want to do that you can throw a IOExcepetion

Comment: plz tell me with example throw a IOExcepetion  OR create this exception? than you

Comment: Just change throw new CanceledException(); to throw new IOException();

Comment: i add your code and stop progressbar notification but i have problems i see wireless connection tralsfer data.i check and i found that only stop progressbar but download is runnig

Comment: Are you sure?? It's quite impossible, cause if you stop the loop that persists your file, how can it continue writing on that? You can see the file's size continues increasing even stop has been pressed with some File Manager is better and more secure than see wireless log.

Comment: It's your code? Or you are trying to reproduce someones example? Manage Thread's in android isn't a good pratice as we have asynctasks and IntentServices that can do all hard work to us. I can't see what is going wrong in your code, but my hint for you is to use a AsyncTask or an IntentService to do that, it will make your life easier. If you use AsyncTask to stop your download all you have to do is check in your loop if asynctask isCancelled(), and if you use an IntentService a simple exception as I mentioned before  would solve your problem.

Comment: if I use asynctask similay http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521 how to cancel plz tell with example thank so much